# Meaning of "interview wasn’t all that"

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

> If the telephone interview **wasn’t all that**, a polite rejection email is sent. Otherwise, both a tech interview and financial negotiation should happen.

<sup>([Spring.io blog](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/08/getting-started-with-activiti-and-spring-boot))</sup>

What exactly "all that" in previous paragraph means? It almost seems to me like there is a word missing. What are the rules for using the phrase this way?

Comment: Yes, normally "all that" would be followed by an adjective.  It does exist as a relatively uncommon idiom on its own, but I'm having trouble finding any results for that form of it in google.  The closest example I can give is the 1999 teen romance movie _She's All That_.  In the case of the movie title, it means she's really awesome/cool/etc.  In the example in your question, it means the interview was _not_ all that good.

Comment: I think this may be a co-opted form of the black vernacular expression "ain't all dat" meaning "it isn't all that {good|big a deal|great|etc}.

Comment: I also think there is a word missing, unless @TRomano is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "all that" is a shortened version of the catchphrase "all that and a bag of chips", which was briefly popular in the 1990s.  The intent of "all that and a bag of chips" was to mean something that meets and exceeds expectations, like a lunch that includes something extra at no cost.  It was shorted to "all that" and became a common part of urban/African-American slang for a while, before it was embraced by mainstream commercial pop culture trying to seem timely and young.

In modern usage, "all that" still means exceptional.  Saying something wasn't "all that", therefore, is a way of saying unexceptional, or not impressive.  It is no longer a commonly used phrase unless someone is deliberately (or ironically) trying to reference 90's culture, so I would not expect to see this again.

Answer (score 0):

To get a fuller meaning, an implied phrase to indicate the expectation could be added:

> If the telephone interview wasn’t all that **(it was hoped to be)**, a polite rejection email *would be* sent. Otherwise, both a tech interview and financial negotiation should happen.

Comment: It does work if you parse it that way, but I don't think the author really intended it as short for "all that it was hoped to be".  It's probably the slang expression *all that*, which means something like "that impressive", and is usually used in a negative sense, as in "ain't all that".